# Kafka metrics not exported / not updating

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to monitor kafka lag that is exposed via prometheus `kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max`, but the value is always either `0` or `NaN`

Config

```
factory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
factory.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<>(meterRegistry));
```

Producing

```
public void send(String message) {
    createLagTemplate.sendDefault(message);
}
```

Consuming

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "create-lag", containerFactory = "lagContainerFactory")
public void listen(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
}
```

Now when generating a bunch of messages I can see the lag increase via kafka dashboard.

I can see messages being produced and consumed via metrics

```
kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_consumed_total
kafka_producer_topic_record_send_total
```

I can't see any values from

```
kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max
```

Using boot 2.4.5, micrometer 1.6.6

Am I missing any configuration?